# Nonsensical disassembled ARM instructions

Tags: ida, arm

I have been tracing through my binary and converting it to C code so I can understand it easily. As I am going through the instructions and functions, I keep stumbling upon code that don't make sense. 
For example:

```
ROM:080004B8                 CMNNE.W         R4, #1
ROM:080004BC                 BEQ.W           loc_80007DE
```

This code will never branch.
Another example:

```
STRB.W          R0, [SP,#0x18+var_18] @ where var_18 is -0x18
```

Which is similar to indexing an array in C like this "array[5-5]". Why is this happening? Is this the disassembler? A form of obfuscated code that is trying to frustrate me? A poor compiler?

Comment: Is this code between functions ? Is it ARM or Thumb ?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at ARM code, so I might be totally wrong - why are you saying your first example will never branch? if Z=1, CMNNE is not executed and BEQ branches; If Z=0, CMNNE is executed (testing R4) and BEQ would branch on the result.

Comment: The first example is between functions and the second example is inside a function. It is Thumb. @VitalyOsipov you are correct. I have edited the post by removing that example.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/XS4kb0iV) is a better example. A value from the stack is loaded to R0, shifted, and saved in R0 (the value in the stack does not get updated). The next line loads a different value from the stack which removes the shifted value from the line before. What is the point of these instructions that have no purpose?

Comment: IDA does this for you - intentionally. The reason is it keeps track of modifications of the stack pointer, and yet attempts to keep the (relative!) addresses of local variables the same, Quite helpful actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Rad Lexus' comment, which describes the situation very well but may not be understandable without an example:

Within a function, the stack pointer, in most cases, isn't constant. It may change when parameters for a function/method/subroutine are pushed, when the programmer uses things like `alloca`, and for other reasons as well, depending on the compiler and processor.

This makes tracking the position of arguments and local variables quite hard. For example, code like `f(i++)` may result in something like

```
mov r0, [sp, #8]     ; read the variable
mov [sp], r0          ; put it on the argument stack
sub sp, sp, #4        ; adjust the stack pointer
add r0, r0, #1        ; calculate the ++
mov [sp, #12], r0    ; write back result
```

which is a version that makes the change to `sp` visible; normally, that change will be hidden in something like `stmfd sp!, {r0}`

In such cases, it's quite difficult to see that the "read" and "write" operations access the same address in memory while the `sp` value has changed.

This is why decompilers like IDA assign names to those locations - as an example, let's assume in my example the variable is named `var_4` with a value of 4.

Now IDA can emit

```
mov r0, [sp, var_4+#4]     ; read the variable
mov [sp, var_4+#8], r0     ; write back result
```

with `var_4` hinting at "the same variable", and the `#4`/`#8` at the offset from `[sp]` that needs to be added to `var_4` in each of these cases.